# Django drop down is not giving me the full selected name

Tags: django, django-views

I have a drop down and it is populated through my models. I am able to select one and then push submit. But the data that I am getting is being broke by spaces in the name. So if I have an option in my drop down menu such as:

`Please Pick Me`

I will only get

`Please`

template.html

```
<form action="{% url 'parsed' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel1">Select Test:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="selectedtest" id="sel1">
            {% for test in test %}
                <option value={{ test.name }}>{{ test.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Paste Event JSON</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="jsontextarea" rows="20"></textarea>
            <div style="text-align:center">
                </br>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Parse">
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def parsed(request):
    data = request.POST.get('jsontextarea')
    testname = request.POST.get('selectedtest')
    print(testname)
    context = {
        "json" : data,
        "test" : Test.objects.all(),
        "event" : Event.objects.all(),
        "platform" : Platform.objects.all(),
        "device" : Device.objects.all(),
        "property" : Property.objects.all(),
        "testname" : testname
    }
    return render(request, 'jsonparser/parsed.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

`<option value={{ test.name }}>{{ test.name }}</option>`

with

`<option value="{{ test.name }}">{{ test.name }}</option>` (Notice the double quotes)

My guess is that your HTML becomes -  `<option value=Please Pick Me>Please pick me</option>` and in this case the value of the option is "Please". If you use double quotes however, it would become  `<option value="Please Pick Me">Please pick me</option>` which is what you want